# $A,B\neq0$ then $\langle A x_n, Bx_n\rangle\neq0\;\forall n\geq n_0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F, \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$.

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $F$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{B}(F)$.

> Is the following assertion true?
>   $$(A\neq0\text{ and }B\neq0)\Rightarrow (\text{there exists }n_0\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }\langle A x_n, Bx_n\rangle\neq0\;\forall n\geq n_0)$$

Comment: I don't have enough of a background to feel confident writing a complete answer, but one possible approach that I am thinking of is to let $A$ be an orthogonal projection onto a proper closed subspace of $F$ and to let $B$ be a projection such that $\operatorname{Ran}B=\ker A$, and take $x_n$ to lie in $\ker A$. Then $\langle Ax_n,Bx_n\rangle=0$ for each $n$, but $A,B\neq0$.

Comment: Not if you allow $x_n$ to be (eventually) constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true if $\dim F > 1$. Basically you can have $A(F) \perp B(F)$.

Let $u, v\in F\setminus\{0\}$ be such that $\langle u, v\rangle=0$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the orthogonal projections onto $\mbox{span}\{u\}$ and $\mbox{span}\{v\}$, respectively. Then we have $\langle Ax, Bx\rangle=0$ for every $x\in F$.